# ロードバランサーの設定方法

Tags: google-cloud

GCP上にWordPressを使って、ブログを運営しています。ロードバランサーを使って、負荷分散をして行きたいですのですが、設定方法でつまづいています。ウェブでもなかなかよい説明ブログなどが見つかりません。よくまとまっているサイトなどがあれば教えてください。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　こちらのご質問ですが、今の内容だと質問者さんがどこで躓いているのか分からないため、検索すれば出てくるサイト以外にどういったサイトを推薦すれば良いのか分かりにくく、回答が集まりづらいです。その代わりに、負荷分散をするために今までどのように設定しようとして上手くいかなかったのかの作業ログを質問文に追記して、どこで躓いたのかを具体的に書いていただけると回答が集まりやすくなります。質問文下の「編集」から自由に追記できますので、よろしければお試しください。

Answer (score 0):

GCP使っているのであればkubernetesを使ってみてはいかがでしょうか？
をwordpressであれば
参考資料
https://github.com/utshav2008/k8wordpressmysqlcluster

https://qiita.com/taketora/items/024049272abc47abe3b4